# How to exclude CSS file from Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

My VS 2012 is giving me too much intellisense (Intelligent code completion) as I include more and more CSS files.

Is there a way to exclude some css files from being parsed by the intellisense?

I am trying to reduce the "verbosity" on the CSS suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Sollution explorer > exclude the folder which contain all those css file and click on Show all file.

When solution explorer stop showing you that file it will doesn't show you the css class(es) and ID from that CSS File that you have just excluded right now.